# jQuery double click not working on table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I am downloading a table from a remote database but when I do this I am having an issue implementing a double click function on the rows in the table. I am able to do the double click function on the whole table though using just the id for the table like this `$('#t01').dblclick(function(){`. I think it is because I am generating the html text for the table on the server side. I tried using the function on the EditTable that I created fully on the client side and it worked fine. Has anyone any idea how I could get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

html code:

```
<section class="main-section" id="service"><!--main-section-start-->
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Mapping</h2>


        <div data-role="content">
            <table id="t01">
            </table>

            <br>
            <br>
            <button data-role="button" id="upload">Upload</button>

            <table id="EditTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td><td>One</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td><td>Two</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var trackID = new Array();
function onBodyLoad() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ec2*******************compute.amazonaws.com/downloadAdmin.php',
        success: function (data) {
    // document.getElementById("tblDiv").innerHTML = data;
        var trackID=data.split(" ") ;
     //alert(data);
        printDatabase(trackID);
        }
    });

}

function printDatabase(trackID){
        var tblText='<table style="width:100%"><tr><th style="text-align:center">Recent Journeys</th></tr>';
            var len = trackID.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                tblText +='<tr id="\''+trackID[i]+'\'"><td style="text-align:center">' 
                + trackID[i] +'</td></tr>';

            }
            tblText +="</table>";
            document.getElementById("t01").innerHTML =tblText;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t01 tr').dblclick(function(){
        alert('Row dblclicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: You're linking the function on elements that don't exist on $(document).ready. It should work when you use $('#t01 tr').dblclick(function() after printDatabase() is finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please replace

```
$('#t01 tr').dblclick(function(){
  alert('Row dblclicked');
});
```

With

```
$(document).on("dblclick","#t01 tr",function() {
  alert('Row dblclicked');
});
```

To capture events on elements which are created AFTER declaring your event listeners - you should bind to a parent element, or element higher in the hierarchy. Your table is created dynamically after the page is done loading and jQuery doesn't know about it.

Comment: Yeah that worked! Spent ages trying to find that online, cheers thanks for that :)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your code for initialization of the double click happens AFTER the elements have been created. It's not enough that it's after body load - your AJAX still hasn't returned at that point.

Put the

```
$('#t01 tr').dblclick(function(){
   alert('Row dblclicked');
});
```

after the PrintDatabase() function call in your AJAX success function.